# Caching techniques for objects

Tags: java, oop, caching, dependency-injection

Suppose i have classes `A`,`B`,`C`. `C` has a method `longRunningMethod`, which takes a long time to run and returns an `int`. Classes `A` and `B` both have `C` as a dependency and need to call method `longRunningMethod`:

```
public class A{
    private C c;
    public A(C c){
        this.c = c;
    }
    
    public void method1(){
        this.c.longRunningMethod();
    }
}
```

```
public class B{
    private C c;
    public A(C c){
        this.c = c;
    }
    
    public void method2(){
        this.c.longRunningMethod();
    }
}
```

```
public class C{
    
    public int longRunningMethod(){
        ...
    }
}
```

```
public class MyProgram{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        C c = new C();
        A a = new A(c);
        B b = new B(c);
        a.method1();
        b.method2()//avoid calling c.longRunningMethod();
    }
}
```

What approaches can be taken to avoid calling `longRunningMethod` twice? Of course, the simple approach is to change the constructor argument of `A` and `B` to `int` and call `longRunningMethod` once in `MyProgram`. But then, it is not that obvious to what to pass to `A` and `B` (which `int`s are allowed?).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class C{
    private boolean wasCalled = false;
    private int cachedValue;

    public int longRunningMethod(){
        if (!wasCalled) {
            // do your long running job here and set result to cachedValue
            wasCalled = true;
        }
        return cachedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution will not work because if 'longRunningMethod()' is called by A, 'wasCalled' value is still 'false' and if the method is called by B while 'longRunningMethod' is still "running",  the 'longRunningMethod' will be executed also